# How can I transition from tile to stained concrete?

Tags: concrete, tile, transition

What are some good ways to transition from tile to stained concrete? We pulled up the carpet that was next to our tile and stained the floor instead of new carpet?  I am looking for simple DIY transition ideas

Comment: Is there a change in elevation between the two surfaces? Even small, like the height of the tile alone.

Answer (score 1):

This simplest tile transition is the integral metal edge.[image] It comes in quite a few profiles, some of which can handle a small amount of elevation change. If you need something more elaborate I'd really need more details and hopefully some pictures.